# Text on search button is unreadable in IE7/8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

The text on the search box is supposed to be displayed as 'Find' but sometimes in IE7/8 the text is unreadable.

[image: text scribbled]

When the user scrolls up and down the page to view the search results, the text on the button disappears.

[image: text disappears]

CSS:

```css
#search-primary .search-inputs td.submit input {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
    _padding: 2px 0.2em 3px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You'll need to post some code or an example.

Comment: If possible, post the URL where you are trying this. (I'd like to run it through the W3C validation service.)

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or didn't happen

Comment: @BrianStinar, it is an internal site I unfortunately cannot post the URL. The only other issue I can think of is this seems to be happening only after the user sets the parameters in the Advanced Search form, which in turn calls a javascript function

Comment: @eLearner If you can't post the URL, post the HTML/CSS code that made this happen. We can't examine the bits in the screenshot you posted to search for syntax errors.

Comment: @Archio, here is the CSS: #search-primary .search-inputs td.submit input {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 17px;
_padding: 2px 0.2em 3px;
width: 60px;
margin-top: -1px;
height: 30px;
}

Comment: @eLearner ... are you serious? You want help but cant paste html / css code for this???? Go away... or EDIT your post and paste some HTML + CSS what makes this happen!

Comment: sorry, I accidentally posted that, will update the question with css and html snippets

Comment: `_padding`. That a typo?

Comment: @j08691, that's an [IE underscore hack](http://wellstyled.com/css-underscore-hack.html)

Comment: @steveax - thanks. I refuse to use hacks for IE which explains why I didn't recognize it.

Comment: @eLearner, you need to post a minimal document that demonstrates the problem. This means that you need to try and isolate the issue. Just saying that something happens sometimes isn’t enough, when the code posted, tested in a minimal environment, does not have the problem. (I’m sure the problem is real; I’ve seen similar things happening.)

Comment: This post by Mike Badgley did the trick.http://www.lifeathighroad.com/web-development/fixed-ie7-button-text-redraw-bug/

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: scroll;  /* IE8 fix */
```

worked for me